# Software for supply chain visibility

Tags: inventory

I work in a manufacturing company as a sales manager. I want a software for the supply chain visibility. 
Requirements are :
1) According to delivery date, reverse calculation tells at what different date 
   raw material, packing should be available. 
2) Dynamic Views
3) Every person responsible in supply chain can change the date and thus new delivery date calculates
4) Alerts for the order I want if delivery dates changes or late

Comment: Welcome aboard! Please read [ask] and state a budget, if you have one, or use the [tag:gratis tag] . Also, which operating system should it run on? Please us the relevant tag[s].

I expect that you already have a database of information? Please tell us whether or not. If not, and you are happy use the app’s recommendation, then there are probably more answer, fewer to use your won database, but you have to tell us. Basically, the more details you give us, the better that we can help you. I hope that you (update your question and) get an answer, as I would be interested too ;-)